# UISlider problem - how to detect a user releasing the slider button in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I can detect the value change event from the UISlider, but now I need to detect a user releasing the slider button.

How to detect this event (or touch on slider ends) ?

Should I use the "touch up inside" event for detection ?

Thanks.

Comment: Not the perfect solution but if you don't need to track the changes, you can turn off continuous property of slider. This will give you one event and that will be fired when user will release the slider.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the UISlider's `UIControlEventValueChanged`. Set the `continuous` property to NO as to initiate when the user is done selecting a value.

```
[mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
mySlider.continuous = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

I've not worked with sliders, however as UISlider inherits from UIView - surely you can just tap into touchesBegan: and touchesEnded: to perform your task.

Answer (score 2):

Through IB you can attach "Touch Up Inside" and "Touch Up Outside" to a method/action of the viewController for slider release.

Or more programmatically (probably in your viewController), you can use

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action 
                   forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

to detect when the `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` and `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` events occur to your UISlider.

**References**

- [method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [control events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events)

Answer (score 0):

`UIControlEventTouchDown` event to detect when the user starts using the control. `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` when the user finishes using the slider. To add the event just do as @JohnK suggested